# How to return ArrayList as SoapObject

Tags: android, arraylist, ksoap

Iam new to Android and stuck up with something for past couple of days.
Iam retreiving `CandidateNames` from database and storing it to my `ArrayList` which is in a `WebService` and returning the `ArrayList` to Java Client.

`WebService` with `ArrayList`:

```
public  ArrayList<String> DisplayName(){
    ArrayList<String>  results= new ArrayList<String>(); 
    try {
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName";
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,"username","pswd");
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        String QueryString = "Select CName From CMaster where cid='xyz'";
        rs = statement.executeQuery(QueryString);

        while (rs.next()) {
            results.add(rs.getString(1));
        }

        rs.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return results;
}
```

**Java Code:**

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);            
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true; 
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();    
    System.out.println("Response:::::::::::::" +result);
}
```

This gives me only the first value of my `ArrayList`.
When I replace: `SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();` with

`SoapObject result= (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                 System.out.println("Response:::::::::::::" +result.getProperty(0));`
it throws the following `exception`:

```
java.lang.classcastexception org.ksoap2.serialization.soapprimitive cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.soapObject
```

I Googled and tried every possible thing,please help me out if i missed out something.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show the response output as SoapPrimitive?

Comment: SoapPrimitive gives me the value of ArrayList at index 0,that is the first value of my ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Hope it helps. I also have a WS whihc is returning an Arraylist

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
int count = result.getPropertyCount();
ArrayList<String> simplifiedList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    simplifiedList.add(result.getPropertyAsString(i));
}
```

So in this point you have an Arraylist, simplifiedList whihc you can pass it to another activity or to do anything else with it.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I worked with a WS which returned an ArrayList, and my Object_A had their own ArrayList the same for Object_B their own ArrayList, whatever I've solved with this:

`SoapObject myArray_A=null;`

`SoapObject myArray_B=null;`

`SoapObject myArray_C=null;`

```
myArray_A=envelop.bodyIn;
for(int x=0; x<myArray_A.getPropertyCount()-1;x++){

myArray_B = (SoapObject) myArray_A.getProperty(x);
for(int y=0; y<myArray_B.getPropertyCount()-1;y++){
    myArray_C = (SoapObject) myArray_B.getProperty(y);
    for(int z=0; z<myArray_C.getPropertyCount()-1;z++){
        SoapPrimitive porperty = (SoapPrimitive) myArray_B.getProperty(z);
    }
}}
```